# What is the best way to integrate different Excel files with different sheets with different formats in Python?

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I have multiple Excel files with different sheets in each file, these files have been made my people, so each one has different formats, different number of columns and also different structures to represent the data.
For example, in one sheet, the dataframe/table starts at 8th row, second column. In other it starts at 122 row, etc...

I want to retrieve something in common from these Excels, it is variable names and information.

However, I don't how could I possibly retrieve all this information without needing to parse each individual file. This is not an option because there are lot of these files with lots of sheets in each file.

I have been thinking about using regex as well as edit distance between words, but I don't know if that is the best option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any common thing between the different formats to identify the column of interest? (I'm assuming the values are all in columns, regardless of where they begin in the sheet). I think your question is too vague for a meaningful answer. Is the data similar in any meaningful way? (is it a numerical column? does it have a certain range?)

Comment: Yes the there are tables in different positions of the sheets, however each header of the tables uses different but similar names. The reason the question is too vague is because the problem is vague, there are lots of files with different formats with different column names in different orders.

Comment: Would it be feasible to manually create lists of column header synonyms? Then loop over each workbook and each sheet, looking for any of the known headers, skipping blank rows and columns?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Yes, it could be possible, but I don't think this is a very good approach because people could change header names, header orders. Also parsing all sheets of the excel searching for the tables it will cost lot of time. I think the only way to  solve this problem is to tell the people to make a standard format for the excels.

Comment: I agree, it looks like the best alternative would be to distribute an excel template with standard names. The idea you suggest in your question is possibly among the best, you can define fancier similarity metrics rather than regex, but I don't know of any technique that will solve the underlying issue

Comment: @torresmateo would you like to write a comprehensive answer to this question? Just saying what you just did on the comment but a bit more extended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will divide my answer into what I think you can do now, and suggestions for the future (if feasible).

#### An attempt to "solve" the problem you have with existing files.

Without regularity on your input files (such as *at least* a common name in the column), I think what you're describing is among the best solutions. Having said that, perhaps a "fancier" similarity metric between column names would be more useful than using regular expressions.

If you believe that there will be ***some*** regularity in the column names, you could look at string distances such as the [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), and using a threshold on the distance that works for you. As an example, let's say that you have a function `d(a:str, b:str) -> float` that calculates a distance between column names, you could do something like this:

```py
# this variable is a small sample of "expected" column names
plausible_columns = [
    'interesting column',
    'interesting',
    'interesting-column',
    'interesting_column',
]

for f in excel_files:
    # process the file until you find columns 
    # I'm assuming you can put the colum names into 
    # a variable `columns` here. 
    for c in columns:
        for p in plausible_columns:
            if d(c,p) < threshold:
                # do something to process the column, 
                # add to a pandas DataFrame, calculate the mean, 
                # etc.
```

If the data itself can tell you something on whether you should process it (such as having a particular distribution, or being in a particular range), you can use such features to decide on whether you should be using that column or not. Even better, you can use *many* of these characteristics to make a finer decision.

Having said this, I don't think a fully automated solution exists without inspecting some of the data manually, and studying the ditribution of the data, or variability in the names of the columns, etc.

#### For the future

Even with fancy methods to calculate features and doing some data analysis on the data you have right now, I think it would be impossible to ensure that you will always get the data you need (by the very nature of the problem). A reasonable way to solve this, in my opinion (and if this is feasible in whatever context you're working in), is to impose a stricter format in the data generation end (I suppose this is a manual thing with people inputting data to excel directly). I would argue that the best solution is to get rid of the problem at the root, and create a unified form, or excel sheet format, and distribute it to the people that will fill the files with data, so that you can ensure the data is then automatically ingested minimizing the risk of errors.